# two predicates in one sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

> Next, previous work **shows**, the scout **recruits** a new scout to join her on a trek to the good site. She dashes around tapping her antennae on other ants and releasing a pheromone from her sting gland, explains Stephen Pratt of Arizona State University in Tempe. Usually she finds a volunteer within a minute or so, and the two set off tandem running.

Please help me comprehend why two predicates, shows and recruits, were used in one sentence by the author ? I think a period should've been used here.

Comment: Definitely not a period. Hint: the sentence could be reworded something like "Previous work shows what happens next: the scout recruits a new scout to join her..."

Comment: What is a "parenthetical phrase"?

Comment: "Previous work shows" is _parenthetical_. Instead of surrounding it with commas you could put it in brackets. Because it's parenthetical you can leave it out altogether and not change the meaning of the sentence fundamentally (although you would lose some information), this means that 'shows' is not a predicate of the main part of the sentence, it is a part of the parenthesis.